# Deleting pending requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

I have created an API using a code ready made from a twilio blog post which I have modified. The code's use is to parse an incoming mail that is sent to "anything"@parse."mydomain".gr and forward it to a mobile number as an sms message. The problem is that if a mail cannot be forwarded for some reason (e.g. text body is more than 1600 characters) it keeps trying and sends error messages in the logs, or sends the messages long after the actual email was forwarded. So I was wondering if it is possible to delete requests already made, and/or "drop" future requests if not successfully fulfilled after say 10000ms. Also I would like to know if I can see the "pending" requests that exist right now somehow. Below is the code I am using.

```
const util = require('util');
const multer = require('multer');
const addrs = require("email-addresses");
const twilio = require('twilio');
//rev.1 
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
//end rev.1

module.exports = async (req, res) => { 
const client = twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
await util.promisify(multer().any())(req, res);

const from = req.body.from;
const to = req.body.to;
const subject = req.body.subject;
const body = req.body.text;

//Using email-addresses library to extract email details.
const toAddress = addrs.parseOneAddress(to);
const toName = toAddress.local;
const fromAddress = addrs.parseOneAddress(from);
const fromName = fromAddress.local;

//Sending SMS with Twilio Client
client.messages.create({
    to: '<mynumber>',
    from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    body: `Message from:${fromName}\n${body}`
}).then(msg => {
    console.log(msg)
    res.status(200).send(msg.sid);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
//rev.1
//define cancelation function 

function cancelation () {
   client.messages(msg.sid)
  .update({status: 'canceled'})
  .then(message => console.log(message.to));
};

//execute cancelation after 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)
setTimeout(cancelation, 10000); 

//define delete_message function 

function message_delete () {
    client.messages(msg.sid).remove();  
}

//execute cancelation after 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)
setTimeout(message_delete, 10000); 
//end rev.1
};
```

Comment: What has your research turned up? What did you find in the API of the packages you're using? For instance, what does the documentation of the `create` method you're using say about providing a means of cancelling or aborting (or timing out) the request?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful. I searched the accompanying docs and found something that should in theory work (I have updated the code) but it does not for some reason. I am beginning to suspect that it might not actually be possible.